# How to ng build angular with json so that after ng build, json values can be replaced manually to show different results?

Tags: json, angular, offline

If not possible any alternative to ng build?
Problem is in the build json values are embeded in main.js making impossible to alter json values later. I want to create a report in HTML with a json file format using angular which can be viewed offline. So later when i wish to change value,  i only need to alter value in json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a config file, add the file in angular.json so that it's included in the dist folder when your app is built, then add a couple of properties to the tsconfig file so that your typescript knows how to import a json file and treat it as a module.

I wrote a detailed blog post walking you through how to do it step-by-step and how it works. You can find that here => https://dev.to/kylerjohnson26/build-your-angular-app-once-deploy-anywhere-5ggk

This will allow you to easily interact with your json config values from your code simply by importing it wherever you want to use it. Most of all, most deployment tools (like Octopus) have native support for json config files so you can easily replace values based on which environment you're deploying to. This is the simplest way to setup your config so that you can "build once and deploy anywhere".

Comment: Thank you very much. This blog of your helped. Although it doesn't completely answer to my requirements. By following the blog, the whole json value will be embeded into mainjs in one place, then as per requirement i modify the json value in the backend by modifying main.js. thanks again.

Comment: The json file in my example is not embedded into the main.js bundle. It is included in the dist folder as a separate file. You can access the entire json structure in your angular app and even update it because the changes to the tsconfig make it just another typescript module

Comment: The step of adding {"resolveJsonModule": true} requires typescript 2.9 or above , I was working with 2.7 so got error and had skipped this step. I am unable to upgrade it though upgraded angular to 10. that's a different issue though. surely it works . Thanks.

Comment: @Abhilash Ah okay. I understand now. If you're having trouble updating your Angular version, try using the Angular Update Guide. You input your current version and the version to which you want to update and it will give you a list of everything you need to do to successfully upgrade. It has helped me tremendously! I should note also that updating one major version at a time makes things far easier, too.
https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to store your JSON in the `assets` folder and then fetch it with an HTTP GET. Then when your app is deployed, you can simply swap out the JSON file for a different one.

Store the json - `assets/test.json`:

```
{
  "message": "hello"
}
```

Get the JSON with `HttpClient`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './my-app.component.html'
})
export class MyAppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/assets/test.json').subscribe(resp => {
        alert(resp['message']);
    });
  }
}
```

[Here's a stackblitz demonstrating this.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-local-data-mamvti)

Comment: This way I am facing cors issue. saying:
from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a CORs issue because you're coming from the same origin. I updated my sample code (note the slash before "assets" - maybe that's why?). I added a stackblitz demonstrating it working.

Comment: no CORS when running on a real or simulated server. But when you build it and open index.html in offline, you will face cors. I have tried again and again. Your solution will work when we go online. But I am delivering html report, so user will open that index.html file offline without server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a way is to add your json in assets in your angular-json file

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "myJson.json",
    "web.config"
  ],
```

here is supposed that the file is in same folder of the main. If you put it in assets folder, you can try user the path "./assets/myJson.json",
in this way, after build, the file will be left and you can edit it.

Comment: I had done that. Asset will be created but will have no coordination with rest of the code. I mean modifying json will not modify html view. @ Kyler Johnson solution works for my requirement. Thanks for coming to help.